# Brave Browser and Google Play Store

Tags: browser, google-play, brave-browser

This question might not belong here but I wanted to know the answers to my question. I tried searching all over internet but didn't find any answers.

**My question is Why Brave Browser is still in Play Store?**

Though brave is a good browser it doesn't follows Google's guidelines.

*According to Google:*

> No one is allowed for background play of the YouTube video player. Example: Using
> YouTube’s API to allow videos to play even when your API service
> window is closed or minimized.

We can play YouTube in background using Brave.

> Blocking of ads is illegal

Everone uses Brave to block google and YouTube ads. Still it is in Play store but why.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Neutral Me

No body is here from google play store, you must have to put this quest on play-store Support.

For my understanding, Brave browser is blocking Ads as a normal Ads blocker. so I think this is not a big issue at all.